# How to resolve or skip the share issue of SQLXMLBulkLoad (transaction mode)

Tags: c#, c++, sql-server, xsd, xml-import

I need to import xml file into Microsoft SQL Server database. And I have a xml schema file (`.xsd`) that contains the mapping info for the xml file to be imported. Each valid data line in xml file need to be imported into a database table row with several columns.

Originally I was using `SQLXMLBulkLoad` (Non Transaction Mode - specify a database connection string) to do the job and it works just fine, however, there is a new requirement that need  me to execute a stored procedure on the same database connection that `SQLXMLBulkLoad` uses. The purpose of this stored procedure is to bind the connection with a specific ID for the current user because there might be multiple users importing xml file at the same time. So I have to use transaction mode instead (- specify a database connection rather than a connection string for `SQLXMLBulkLoad`) and which introduce the well known share issue under remote environment. If the xml file is local and the db server is remote, I need to create a shared folder for `SQLXMLBulkLoad` to work. This is bad but can be done.

The problem is the share folder thing is not accepted by our clients, so I need a better solution that could satisfy the new requirement without the share issue.

I've Googled a while and found one solution that might work - `SqlBulkCopy`, but I have trouble with parsing the schema file (`.xsd`) because it contains many `xml-db:table` mapping information.

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: SQLXMLBulkLoad is the mechanism used by the SSIS XML file data source. Why don't you use SSIS to load the data? Another option would be to load the data into a *staging* table first, process it and move it to the final table once you're done

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your reply.  Unfortunately I'm not familiar with SSIS. About staging table, can you describe with more detail? I forget to mention that there might be multiple users importing xml file at the same time.

Comment: sounds you have an application or web site that users use to import XML data. In this case it would be better to deserialize the file in the application and insert the data using eg SqlBulkCopy, or EF/ADO.NET commands, if the file is small. That's why `SQLXMLBulkLoad` isn't used all that much anymore. What application are you building? Desktop? Web? What language? How large are the files?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos It is a desktop application, using `C++`/`C#`. The xml data file won't be large. The problem I have in using `SqlBulkCopy` is that I don't know how to get the mapping information from `.xsd` file. The schema file is a little complex for there are foreign key relation between different entities.